# gas fittings rusting

Tags: plumbing, deck, gas

I ran a gas line under my deck for a future bbq hook up and outdoor gas fireplace. I didn't think much of the fittings I used and after a few days in the rain in Oregon they started to rust. The one in this photo can be replaced or painted easily, but the pipe couplers located under the deck can't.

Does this meet code in Oregon?

[image]

Comment: "How much of a problem is this?" isn't a question we can answer as there's no objective way to quantify such a thing. Please revise to ask something more specific. See the [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: And yes, any non-stainless metal outside should be protected against corrosion (and code usually requires it). That's why the galvanized version exists.

Comment: If that's a straight run through the rim joist you may be able to pull the whole thing out, rebuild it with galvanized to the same length, and run it back in, possibly pulling up one deck board at the house for visibility. Let us know how we can help.